# Why does the setInterval not fire alternating "tick" "tock" every 1000ms and instead fires synchronously every 2000ms?

Tags: javascript

Type this in console too see:

```js
tick = () => console.log(1);

tock = () => console.log(2);

tickID = setInterval(
  () => this.tick(),
  2000
);

console.log(tickID);

tockID = setTimeout(
  console.log(
    setInterval(
      () => this.tock(),
      2000)
  ),

  1000
);
```

I included the two console.logs of the setInterval too show that they dont have the same ID.

I want a clock alternating tick() and tock() every 1000ms.

(please no answers where I use a boolean instead, I dont want that, I want to know why this logic does not work)

Comment: We can't fully answer here because you are using `this` in your code, but you haven't indicated what "wraps" all the code you've shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're executing the 2nd function immediately...

```
tockID = setTimeout(
  console.log(  // <-- this is being executed here, not in 1 second
    setInterval(
      () => this.tock(),
      2000)
  ),

  1000
);
```

Changing it to this will fix it...

```
tockID = setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(
    setInterval(
      () => this.tock(),
      2000)
  );
},
  1000
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide callback to `setTimeout`:

```js
tick = () => console.log(1);

tock = () => console.log(2);

tickID = setInterval(() => tick(), 2000);

console.log(tickID);

tockID = setTimeout(() => setInterval(() => tock(), 2000), 1000);
```